# I am confused between shortest path finding algorithm and graph traversing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, depth-first-search, shortest-path, path-finding

My understanding is that BFS and DFS are graph traversing algorithm while other algorithms like A* and dijkstra are for finding shortest path between two nodes of a graph. But in some places, I see BFS and DFS also stated as shortest path finding algorithm. Please elaborate the difference between graph traversing algorithm and shortest path finding algorithm. Thanks!

Comment: There exists many different algorithms to [traverse graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal). A*, Dijkstra, BFS and DFS are just a few of them.

Comment: What is the difference between traversing graph and finding shortest path between two nodes?

Comment: "Find shortest distance" is a goal, a purpose. "Traversing a graph" is done for many different goals, many different purposes (like finding the shortest path). Your question is about two different subjects that are orthogonal to each other.

Answer (score 0):

"Graph traversal" is any algorithm that iterates over nodes. "Shortest path" means finding the shortest path between two nodes.

Your confusion probably comes from the fact that BFS, a graph traversal algorithm, can also be used to find the shortest path in **unweighted** graphs. Also, both BFS and DFS find the shortest path in trees (since there's always only one path between nodes)